# How to only ask the user for the sign value once and not in every iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

In its current state this code works. It is meant to be a transposition tool for musicians. I cant figure out how to only ask the user for the 'sign' value once and not after every successful iteration.

```py
import time
import sys
usr_list = ['A','BB','B','C','C#','D','EB','E','F','F#','G','AB']
u_list = []
t_list = []




def f():
    usr = int(input('Enter how many chords need to be transposed: '))
    while usr!=0:
        chord = input('\nEnter the chord that needs to be transposed: ').upper()
        if chord not in usr_list:
            print('Invalid Input')
        elif u_list.count(chord) >=1:
            print('Already typed')
        else:
            usr =usr-1
            u_list.append(chord)
            print('Chords that need to be transposed are:',u_list)
    while len(u_list)>0:
        chord = (u_list[0])
        sign = input('''1.Positive Transposition(+)
2.Negative Transpostion(-)

Your choice: ''')
        if sign == '1' or '+':
            sign = '+'
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print('\nPositive shift initiating')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            t_key = int(input('Enter value of transposition: '))
            chord_value = int(usr_list.index(chord))
            chord_transpose = chord_value + t_key
            if chord_transpose >= 12:
                chord_transpose = chord_transpose - 12
                print(usr_list[chord_transpose])
            elif chord_transpose < 12:
                del u_list[0]
                t_list.append(usr_list[chord_transpose])
                print(u_list)
            else:
                print('Invalid Input, Try Again!') 
        elif sign == '2' or '-':
            sign = '-'
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print('\nNegative initiating')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            t_key = int(input('Enter value of transposition: '))
            chord_value = int(usr_list.index(chord))
            chord_transpose = chord_value - t_key
            if chord_transpose >= 12:
                chord_transpose = chord_transpose + 12
                print(usr_list[chord_transpose])
            elif chord_transpose < 12:
                del u_list[0]
                t_list.append(usr_list[chord_transpose])
                print(u_list)
            else:
                print('Invalid')
        else:
            print('Invalid')
        print(t_list)
f()
```

currently it asks the users for a number of chords they want to enter, then transposes them using a list one by one. when asking for the sign value I do not know how to only ask for that value once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the input statement that assigns `sign` is in your while loop. If you want the user to only be prompted once, you need to either put the input statement before both while loops or in between them.